# Need help with first order logic

Tags: first-order-logic

I'm trying to understand first-order-logic and have this simple question.

Given the following predicates:

$Thing(t)$, which states that $t$ is a thing;

$Word(w)$, which states that $w$ is a word; and

$HurtsYouMoreThan(x,y)$, which states that $x$ hurts you more than $y$,

I need to create a first-order-logic statement that says "**There is nothing that hurts you more than words do.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It will help to re-word it:

> No thing hurts more than words do.

In other words:

> For all $w$ and for all $t$, if $w$ is a word and $t$ is a thing, it is not true that $t$ hurts you more than $w$.

$$(\forall{w})(\forall{t}){(\operatorname{word}(w)\land\operatorname{thing}(t))\to\lnot\operatorname{HurtsYouMoreThan}(t,w)}$$

Comment: I updated the statement to be less slangy.

Comment: @Victor: This is arguably not quite correct. There is nothing in the statement of the problem that rules out the possibility that a word is a thing, and it is not explicitly stated that $\forall x(\neg\text{HurtsYouMoreThan}(x,x))$. If you use this translation, you should say that you’re assuming that $\forall x(\neg\text{HurtsYouMoreThan}(x,x))$.

Comment: Can you please look at related problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452231/how-to-use-first-order-logic-with-both-constants-and-predicates

Answer (score 1):

**Revised to match new question.**

HINT: *There is nothing that hurts you more than words do* can be understood as follows:

> If $x$ is anything other than a word, and $y$ is any word, then $x$ does not hurt you more than $y$ does.

From here the translation into a sentence of first-order logic using your three predicates should be pretty straightforward. Note that you will have a couple of quantifiers.

Comment: I updated the statement to be less slangy.

Comment: @Victor The tricky part is, it could be argued that $\operatorname{word}(w)\to\operatorname{thing}(t)$ as Brian M. Scott's answer suggests, so it really all depends on how rigorously these predicates are defined. Just something to be mindful of.

Comment: Can you please look at related problem http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/452231/how-to-use-first-order-logic-with-both-constants-and-predicates

Answer (score 0):

**Hint**: If I'm interpreting the given sentence correctly, you should be able to think about this as a sentence more like $$\text{Given any thing $$X which isn't a word and any thing $Y$ which is a word, ...}$$